# How to accept characters in JSpinner

Tags: java, swing

I have document which converts input 1M to 1000000. This works fine if I set document to JTextfield. But when I set this to textfield of a JSpinner. It doesnt work because the spinner internally rejects the invalid values like "m". so if i type 1m , only 1 is sent to the document as input string. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are you expecting the JSpinner to do when it contains "1M" and the user presses the JSpinner's up or down arrows?

Comment: I expect the textfield to change the value as 1000000 and then clicking on up arrow it must change to 1000000+step size

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The below example may help. Please see the comment in the below code

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class jspinnerdemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f= new JFrame("JSpinner Demo");
        f.setSize(500,100);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));
        JSpinner ctrlSpin = new JSpinner();
        //Below code will get the text field (JFormattedTextField) component 
        //from the jspinner and set its format to null
        ((JSpinner.NumberEditor)ctrlSpin.getComponent(2)).getTextField().setFormatterFactory(null);
        JButton ctrlButton = new JButton("Click");
        JTextField ctrlTxt = new JTextField("");
        f.add(ctrlSpin);
        f.add(ctrlButton);
        f.add(ctrlTxt);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
        ctrlButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //So when get the text from the textfield it will return the text as what typed
                ctrlTxt.setText(""+((JSpinner.NumberEditor)ctrlSpin.getComponent(2)).getTextField().getText());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A JSpinner.NumberEditor requires a DecimalFormat, so you'll have to provide a custom DecimalFormat:

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel());

final Map<String, Long> multipliers = new HashMap<>();
multipliers.put("K", 1_000L);
multipliers.put("M", 1_000_000L);
multipliers.put("G", 1_000_000_000L);
multipliers.put("T", 1_000_000_000_000L);

DecimalFormat letterFormat = new DecimalFormat(",##0") {
    @Override
    public Number parse(String text,
                        ParsePosition pos) {
        int len = text.length();
        if (len > 0) {
            String lastChar = text.substring(len - 1, len);
            lastChar = lastChar.toUpperCase(Locale.US);
            Long multiplier = multipliers.get(lastChar);
            if (multiplier != null) {
                Number value =
                    super.parse(text.substring(0, len - 1), pos);
                if (value == null) {
                    return null;
                }

                // Skip past multiplier char.
                pos.setIndex(pos.getIndex() + lastChar.length());

                if (value instanceof BigDecimal) {
                    return ((BigDecimal) value).multiply(
                        BigDecimal.valueOf(multiplier));
                } else if (value instanceof BigInteger) {
                    return ((BigInteger) value).multiply(
                        BigInteger.valueOf(multiplier));
                } else if (value instanceof Double ||
                           value instanceof Float) {
                    return value.doubleValue() * multiplier;
                } else {
                    return value.longValue() * multiplier;
                }
            }
        }

        return super.parse(text, pos);
    }
};

JSpinner.DefaultEditor editor =
    (JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor();
NumberFormatter formatter = (NumberFormatter)
    editor.getTextField().getFormatter();
formatter.setFormat(letterFormat);
```